# Pagination in codeigniter. Extra set of values passed in to model and db->limit not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

Pagination in codeigniter. 
I can't seem to set the limit of posts on every page (it shows all of them on every page).
I think the links are working (they show on the uri), but they do not select the rows per page.

The model:

```
public function index(  $limit,$start,      $var1,$var2,$var3,$var4 ){

$sql = "SELECT 
        trabalho.var1
        trabalho.var2
        empregos.var3
        empregos.var4
        FROM trabalho.empregos
        JOIN trabalho.empresas
        ON empregos.id_empresa = empresas.id_empresa

        WHERE  
           trabalho.var1 LIKE ?
        OR trabalho.var2 LIKE ?
        OR empregos.var3 LIKE ?
        OR empregos.var4 LIKE ?
        ;";

 $variables_form = array($var1,$var2,$var3,$var4);

$this->db->limit($limit, $start);
$query2 = $this->db->query($sql,$variables_form);
return $query2->result();
}
```

The Controller:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/main_controller/index';
$config['total_rows'] = 10;
$config['per_page'] = 5;
$config['num_links'] = 2;
$config["uri_segment"] = 3;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

$data["info"] = $this->search_display_m->
                    index($config["per_page"], $page, 
                    $var1 = 'a', $var2 = 'a', 
                    $var3 = 'a', $var4 = 'a',
                    );

$data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

And the view:

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

And is there a way to simplify the uri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
public function index(  $limit,$start,      $var1,$var2,$var3,$var4 ){

$sql = "SELECT 
        trabalho.var1
        trabalho.var2
        empregos.var3
        empregos.var4
        FROM trabalho.empregos
        JOIN trabalho.empresas
        ON empregos.id_empresa = empresas.id_empresa

        WHERE  
           trabalho.var1 LIKE ?
        OR trabalho.var2 LIKE ?
        OR empregos.var3 LIKE ?
        OR empregos.var4 LIKE ?
        limit $start, $limit
    ;";

 $variables_form = array($var1,$var2,$var3,$var4);

 $query2 = $this->db->query($sql,$variables_form);
 return $query2->result();
}
```